# If I remove the wp title of my site from the admin settings, will it affect SEO?

Tags: wordpress

I want to replace it with a fancy logo image. I am sure most sites do this... is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the title settings in admin, but change the theme so that the home page don't show the title, but has it in the HTML-title. You could also move the <h1>-title off screen using css.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a great SEO technique to utilize the page title as the main `<h1>` for the site (since it appears on the top of every page). If you don't want it to display, DO NOT use `#headerimg h1 {display:none;}` to hide it, instead try some tricky CSS like this:

```
#headerimg h1 {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -3000px;
 font-size: 1px;
}
```